# Fallout 4 How do i delete multiple bodies at a time

Tags: fallout-4

I wanted to test my defenses at sanctuary so I summoned around 200 ghouls and now the place is littered with corpses is there a way to get rid of all the bodies at once instead of going one by one and disabling one at time. On the bright side my defenses worked great!

Comment: you are probably better off reloading to a save point before you did your experiment.  You DID save right? :)

Comment: I forgot to Before :| so my last was around an hour before I experimented

Comment: you can push up (then enter) on the console to repeat the last line

Comment: You still need to target the bodies.

Comment: 200 dead ghouls?? I'd use the dead bodies as a deterrent to let all other feral ghouls know what will happen if they decide "step on my lawn", so to speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not via console commands.

In order to delete the bodies, you will have to target each body individually and delete them via the console.  There are currently no console commands to distinguish between those 200 ghouls you summoned verses all the other NPCs around the area that were there already.

Alternatively, you may be able to trigger an area reset by going to a far away place and sleep/rest for 30 days straight.  This should be enough time to trigger built-in map area reset and clean up the place.

Comment: I have an odd feeling that I will post this "rest for 30 days" fix a TON.  It works a lot in Skyrim too...

Comment: The default is 24h. "iHoursToClearCorpses from 24 hours to 1." [Fast Corpse despawn](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/36051) - most mods that add random spawns will have altered this for you already, to some people's chagrin : [Disabling Fallout 4 “Creation Club” item/mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/364160/disabling-fallout-4-creation-club-item-mod/364301#comment514746_364301)