# Disabling Fallout 4 "Creation Club" item/mod

Tags: fallout-4

I've started playing Fallout 4 on PC again after a few months away. As I've been fighting, I've noticed that the dead NPCs I kill will despawn/disappear immediately when the battle ends, with the exception of whoever I kill last.

For example, I just picked up a radiant quest to defend Nordhagen beach. Three raiders wearing power armor spawned and I killed all three. (They were just normal raiders, no Legendaries.) After the fight, the quest marked itself complete successfully. I was standing over the body of the last raider, and could loot him. The other two were gone.

This has caused me to have to change my usual strategy to loot bodies as I kill them, which I find very annoying. (Additionally it sometimes causes me to lose out on possibly good loot when fighting high level enemies since I can't just stop and loot while taking fire.)

While I don't play with external mods, I do have a bunch of the "Creation Club" extras which I added between my last time playing and now. These are:

- Gunners v Minutemen
- Modular Military Backpack
- Virtual Workshop: Grid World

Of these, the most likely culprit is Gunners v Minutemen since it's a gameplay extra. The Backpack is just an extra item, and the Virtual World extra is just a settlement enhancement. I've looked around, but I can't figure out how to disable the GvM extra to see if it's what's causing the problem. The page in Creation Club just shows "Installed", and the available options are just "Download" (does nothing/disabled) and "Purchase Credits".

[image: Screenshot of Creation Club page]

**Is it possible to disable this Creation Club item somehow so that I can figure out if it's the cause of the buggy disappearing bodies?** I found some Reddit threads which talked about uninstalling the game, verifying the cache, and then reinstalling it and making sure not to download the particular CC items in question. (I'd like to avoid going this route because my internet connection is pretty flaky so downloading massive files is problematic.)

I did take a peek at LOOT but I wasn't able to identify any of the *.esl as being this particular mod. LOOT didn't show any problems, however.

Basically my goal is just to disable this CC item to see if that fixes the issue. If not, I'll re-enable it and try troubleshooting something else.

Comment: [Piles of Corpses - Increased De-spawn Timer](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/1770/) - not that I'd recommend it if you're using 'war' mods. I wouldn't trade more CTDs for in-game loot. "Basically my goal is [to fix the issue]" - which may break the game if you do 'fix' it, or leave you w/o the content anyway.

Comment: Yeah at this point I'm trying to remove/disable mods, not add more that might potentially break my game. And this gunners v minutemen one added a _lot_ of enemies.

Comment: Adding mid-game is better than removing mid-game imo. Either way you should be starting a new game after any changes. As for breaking *the install* I back up all 80 gigs whenever I try to change stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can delete all the paid mods from your data folder.They all start with the same prefix, i'm not sure if it's the same filename for everyone but i **deleted all the files beginning with 'cc**BGSFO4001' in my data folder. For example 'ccBGSFO4001-PipBoy(Black) - Main.ba2' They're really easy to spot and delete as they're not named like the core files.I've got the **game blocked on my firewall**, and everything runs fine without the files. – [webcache.googleusercontent.com](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:LBgTUQVrZKMJ:https://high-powerweare.weebly.com/blog1/fallout-4-how-to-uninstall-creation-club-mods+&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-b-1-d)

That site kept trying to redirect me to a DL. **Do not download from that site**. You probably shouldn't even click the link.

Comment: I don't really recommend this either. I didn't think that I even had the cc but I do, but IDT this problem came up before I installed *War of the Commonwealth*. 99.9% sure *G vs. M* is the culprit. And I would be surprised if the *timer mod* that I linked above isn't already a part of *WitC* because its options are almost unnecessarily extensive.

Comment: "In overall, {[War of the Commonwealth](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/12395)} includes about 50000 of new placed NPC’s and creatures, around 1500 of new group spawn points and patrol routes in common CW area, around 200 group spawn points and patrol routes in cites, and around 200 Minutemen settlement based conditional patrol groups/routes." - despawn isn't a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: I use *Another Life - Alternative Start Mod* (with nothing, in the middle of nowhere). Looting the second enemy is what 'breaks the game'. Just go with it.

Comment: As soon as I finished the G v M storyline the problem went away so I'm pretty sure it's to blame. I understand why they did it but the despawn is _too_ fast -- I rely on corpse looting for the majority of my income, so I was trying to use the increased spawn rate of gunners to my advantage there as well.