# Fallout 4 crashes after loading in

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-4

Briefly after loading into a save, the game will crash (between 15 seconds to a minute or two after I've loaded in), and crashes to desktop. There is no message in Event Viewer or any kind of logs. I have no mods installed. I've tried:

1. Updating the game/verifying game install through steam.
2. Updating Windows/NVIDIA drivers, restarting the computer
3. Using different saves, of different characters, exit saves, etc. I've even used my friend's save, which work on his install just fine.
4. Resetting graphics settings, changing them to low/medium/high/ultra.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any creation club items? These are _technically_ mods. Also does starting a new game work?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I do have CC items, except I've found there's no way to remove them. It does happen on a new save as well.

Comment: Have you tried using [LOOT](https://loot.github.io/) to check your build order? Since you _are_ using mods via the creation club, this might be a worthwhile step.

Comment: [Disabling Fallout 4 “Creation Club” item/mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/364160/disabling-fallout-4-creation-club-item-mod)

Comment: Unrelated but similar : [Fallout 4 will not get past the initial loading screen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269877/fallout-4-will-not-get-past-the-initial-loading-screen) - that file might be worth a look. "I have no mods installed." - baffling. Maybe try Unofficial F4 Patch, except out of my 272 mods that's not one of them. - Specs? Or do *you* have a save with like 40h on it? I.e., your cpu can run F4....

Comment: #5 I haven't changed anything. But I also let the game update itself....

Answer (score 3):

https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/1637542851364222707/

This seemed to be my problem. I only had a blue screen once, after following someone's advice on a comment to disable CC items. Disabling weapon debris in the graphics settings fixed it.

Comment: Only a problem on Nvidia cards.